# Is there a way to retrieve elements using only local names in a Linq-to-XML query?

Tags: linq-to-xml

Lets assume we have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:RegistryResponse status="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:ResponseStatusType:Failure"
    xmlns:tns="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rs:3.0"
    xmlns:rim="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0">
    <tns:RegistryErrorList highestSeverity="">
        <tns:RegistryError codeContext="XDSInvalidRequest - DcoumentId is not unique."
            errorCode="XDSInvalidRequest"
            severity="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:ErrorSeverityType:Error"/>
    </tns:RegistryErrorList>
 </tns:RegistryResponse>
```

To retrieve RegistryErrorList element, we can do

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(<path to xml file>);
XNamespace ns = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rs:3.0";
XElement errorList = doc.Root.Elements( ns + "RegistryErrorList").SingleOrDefault();
```

but not like this

```
XElement errorList = doc.Root.Elements("RegistryErrorList").SingleOrDefault();
```

Is there a way to do the query without the namespace of the element. Basicly is there something conceptially 
similiar to using local-name() in XPath (i.e. //*[local-name()='RegistryErrorList'])

Comment: I don't know why the stupid Microsoft need the namemspace to query elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var q = from x in doc.Root.Elements()
        where x.Name.LocalName=="RegistryErrorList"
        select x;

var errorList = q.SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

In the "method" syntax the query would look like:

```
XElement errorList = doc.Root.Elements().Where(o => o.Name.LocalName == "RegistryErrorList").SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

The following extension will return a collection of matching elements from any level of an XDocument (or any XContainer).

```
     public static IEnumerable<XElement> GetElements(this XContainer doc, string elementName)
    {
        return doc.Descendants().Where(p => p.Name.LocalName == elementName);
    }
```

Your code would now look like this:

```
var errorList = doc.GetElements("RegistryErrorList").SingleOrDefault();
```